# What's the CFString Equiv of NSString's UTF8String?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm stuck on stoopid today as I can't convert a simple piece of ObjC code to its Cpp equivalent. I have this:

```
  const UInt8 *myBuffer = [(NSString*)aRequest UTF8String];
```

And I'm trying to replace it with this:

```
  const UInt8 *myBuffer = (const UInt8 *)CFStringGetCStringPtr(aRequest, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

This is all in a tight unit test that writes an example HTTP request over a socket with CFNetwork APIs. I have working ObjC code that I'm trying to port to C++. I'm gradually replacing NS API calls with their toll free bridged equivalents. Everything has been one for one so far until this last line. This is like the last piece that needs completed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is one of those things where Cocoa does all the messy stuff behind the scenes, and you never really appreciate just how complicated things can be until you have to roll up your sleeves and do it yourself.

The simple answer for why it's not 'simple' is because `NSString` (and `CFString`) deal with all the complicated details of dealing with multiple character sets, Unicode, etc, etc, while presenting a simple, uniform API for manipulating strings.  It's object oriented at its best- the details of 'how' `(NS|CF)String` deals with strings that have different string encodings (UTF8, MacRoman, UTF16, ISO 2022 Japanese, etc) is a private implementation detail.  It all 'just works'.

It helps to understand how `[@"..." UTF8String]` works.  This is a private implementation detail, so this isn't gospel, but based on observed behavior.  When you send a string a `UTF8String` message, the string does something approximating (not actually tested, so consider it pseudo-code, and there's actually simpler ways to do the exact same thing, so this is overly verbose):

```
- (const char *)UTF8String
{
  NSUInteger utf8Length = [self lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSMutableData *utf8Data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:utf8Length + 1UL];
  char *utf8Bytes = [utf8Data mutableBytes];
  [self     getBytes:utf8Bytes
           maxLength:utf8Length
          usedLength:NULL
            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
             options:0UL
               range:NSMakeRange(0UL, [self length])
      remainingRange:NULL];
  return(utf8Bytes);
}
```

You don't have to worry about the memory management issues of dealing with the buffer that `-UTF8String` returns because the `NSMutableData` is autoreleased.

A string object is free to keep the contents of the string in whatever form it wants, so there's no guarantee that its internal representation is the one that would be most convenient for your needs (in this case, UTF8).  If you're using just plain C, you're going to have to deal with managing some memory to hold any string conversions that might be required.  What was once a simple `-UTF8String` method call is now much, much more complicated.

Most of `NSString` is actually implemented in/with CoreFoundation / `CFString`, so there's obviously a path from a `CFStringRef` -> `-UTF8String`.  It's just not as neat and simple as `NSString`'s `-UTF8String`.  Most of the complication is with memory management.  Here's how I've tackled it in the past:

```
void someFunction(void) {
  CFStringRef cfString; // Assumes 'cfString' points to a (NS|CF)String.

  const char *useUTF8StringPtr = NULL;
  UInt8 *freeUTF8StringPtr = NULL;

  CFIndex stringLength = CFStringGetLength(cfString), usedBytes = 0L;

  if((useUTF8StringPtr = CFStringGetCStringPtr(cfString, kCFStringEncodingUTF8)) == NULL) {
    if((freeUTF8StringPtr = malloc(stringLength + 1L)) != NULL) {
      CFStringGetBytes(cfString, CFRangeMake(0L, stringLength), kCFStringEncodingUTF8, '?', false, freeUTF8StringPtr, stringLength, &usedBytes);
      freeUTF8StringPtr[usedBytes] = 0;
      useUTF8StringPtr = (const char *)freeUTF8StringPtr;
    }
  }

  long utf8Length = (long)((freeUTF8StringPtr != NULL) ? usedBytes : stringLength);

  if(useUTF8StringPtr != NULL) {
    // useUTF8StringPtr points to a NULL terminated UTF8 encoded string.
    // utf8Length contains the length of the UTF8 string.

    // ... do something with useUTF8StringPtr ...
  }

  if(freeUTF8StringPtr != NULL) { free(freeUTF8StringPtr); freeUTF8StringPtr = NULL; }
}
```

**NOTE**: I haven't tested this code, but it is modified from working code.  So, aside from obvious errors, I believe it should work.

The above tries to get the pointer to the buffer that `CFString` uses to store the contents of the string.  If `CFString` happens to have the string contents encoded in UTF8 (or a suitably compatible encoding, such as ASCII), then it's likely `CFStringGetCStringPtr()` will return non-`NULL`.  This is obviously the best, and fastest, case.  If it can't get that pointer for some reason, say if `CFString` has its contents encoded in UTF16, then it allocates a buffer with `malloc()` that is large enough to contain the entire string when its is transcoded to UTF8.  Then, at the end of the function, it checks to see if memory was allocated and `free()`'s it if necessary.

And now for a few tips and tricks... `CFString` 'tends to' (and this is a private implementation detail, so it can and does change between releases) keep 'simple' strings encoded as MacRoman, which is an 8-bit wide encoding.  MacRoman, like UTF8, is a superset of ASCII, such that all characters < 128 are equivalent to their ASCII counterparts (or, in other words, any character < 128 is ASCII).  In MacRoman, characters >= 128 are 'special' characters.  They all have Unicode equivalents, and tend to be things like extra currency symbols and 'extended western' characters. See [Wikipedia - MacRoman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) for more info.  But just because a `CFString` says it's MacRoman (`CFString` encoding value of `kCFStringEncodingMacRoman`, `NSString` encoding value of `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding`) doesn't mean that it has characters >= 128 in it.  If a `kCFStringEncodingMacRoman` encoded string returned by `CFStringGetCStringPtr()` is composed entirely of characters < 128, then it is exactly equivalent to its ASCII (`kCFStringEncodingASCII`) encoded representation, which is also exactly equivalent to the strings UTF8 (`kCFStringEncodingUTF8`) encoded representation.

Depending on your requirements, you may be able to 'get by' using `kCFStringEncodingMacRoman` instead of `kCFStringEncodingUTF8` when calling `CFStringGetCStringPtr()`.  Things 'may' (probably) be faster if you require strict UTF8 encoding for your strings but use `kCFStringEncodingMacRoman`, then check to make sure the string returned by `CFStringGetCStringPtr(string, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman)` only contains characters that are < 128. If there are characters >= 128 in the string, then go the slow route by `malloc()`ing a buffer to hold the converted results.  Example:

```
CFIndex stringLength = CFStringGetLength(cfString), usedBytes = 0L;

useUTF8StringPtr = CFStringGetCStringPtr(cfString, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

for(CFIndex idx = 0L; (useUTF8String != NULL) && (useUTF8String[idx] != 0); idx++) {
  if(useUTF8String[idx] >= 128) { useUTF8String = NULL; }
}

if((useUTF8String == NULL) && ((freeUTF8StringPtr = malloc(stringLength + 1L)) != NULL)) {
  CFStringGetBytes(cfString, CFRangeMake(0L, stringLength), kCFStringEncodingUTF8, '?', false, freeUTF8StringPtr, stringLength, &usedBytes);
  freeUTF8StringPtr[usedBytes] = 0;
  useUTF8StringPtr = (const char *)freeUTF8StringPtr;
}
```

Like I said, you don't really appreciate just how much work Cocoa does for you automatically until you have to do it all yourself.  :)

Comment: Now that's an explanation! Thanx Johne! I tried your code and now I have another issue. Because I started with ObjC in a ".m" file I was able to quickly mock up an example. Now that I'm converting to C++ using a ".mm" file I get exceptions on build:
Undefined symbols:
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr in libMyNetworking.a(MyLowLevelNetworking.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
I still feel so clueless to Apple tools at times...

Answer (score 5):

In the sample code above, the following appears:

```
CFIndex stringLength = CFStringGetLength(cfString)
```

stringLength is then being used to malloc() a temporary buffer of that many bytes, plus 1.

But the header file for `CFStringGetLength()` expressly says it returns the number of 16-bit Unicode characters, not bytes.  So if some of those Unicode characters are outside the ASCII range, the `malloc()` buffer won't be long enough to hold the UTF-8 conversion of the string.

Perhaps I'm missing something, but to be absolutely safe, the number of bytes needed to hold N arbitrary Unicode characters is at most 4*n, when they're all converted to UTF-8.

Comment: what's wrong with `CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding` ?

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001211-CH201-F11138):

> Whether or not this function returns a valid pointer or NULL depends on many factors, all of which depend on how the string was created and its properties. In addition, the function result might change between different releases and on different platforms. So do not count on receiving a non-NULL result from this function under any circumstances.

You should use `CFStringGetCString` if `CFStringGetCStringPtr` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Close but no cigar. I'm now using:
  CFStringGetCString(aRequest, myBuffer, [(NSString*)aRequest length], kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

and it almost works but the first character is truncated. Basically how do I get a String pointer from a CFStringRef? Why is it so hard?

Comment: You might want to use [aRequest length]+1 to account for the null-terminator.

Comment: The reason, as far as I can tell, for all the hassle is that the internal representation of the CFString may not be UTF8, so there may not *be* a raw pointer to get.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some working code. I started with @johne's answer, replaced `CFStringGetBytes` with `CFStringGetLength` for simplicity, and made the correction suggested by @Doug.

```
const char *useUTF8StringPtr = NULL;
char *freeUTF8StringPtr = NULL;

if ((useUTF8StringPtr = CFStringGetCStringPtr(cfString, kCFStringEncodingUTF8)) == NULL)
{
    CFIndex stringLength = CFStringGetLength(cfString);
    CFIndex maxBytes = 4 * stringLength + 1;
    freeUTF8StringPtr = malloc(maxBytes);
    CFStringGetCString(cfString, freeUTF8StringPtr, maxBytes, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    useUTF8StringPtr = freeUTF8StringPtr;
}

// ... do something with useUTF8StringPtr... 

if (freeUTF8StringPtr != NULL)
    free(freeUTF8StringPtr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's destined for a socket, perhaps [`CFStringGetBytes()`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetBytes) would be your best choice?

Also note that the documentation for `CFStringGetCStringPtr()` says:

> This function either returns the requested pointer immediately, with no memory allocations and no copying, in constant time, or returns `NULL`. If the latter is the result, call an alternative function such as the `CFStringGetCString` function to extract the characters.

Comment: That has, like a million parameters. I guess I could fill out its 1080 form which looks like it'll leave me in the same position. I'll post back in a moment with results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to printf a CFStringRef which implies we get a '\0'-terminated string from a CFStringRef:

```
// from: http://lists.apple.com/archives/carbon-development/2001/Aug/msg01367.html
// by Ali Ozer
// gcc -Wall -O3 -x objective-c -fobjc-exceptions -framework Foundation test.c

#import <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/*
This function will print the provided arguments (printf style varargs) out to the console.
Note that the CFString formatting function accepts "%@" as a way to display CF types.
For types other than CFString and CFNumber, the result of %@ is mostly for debugging
and can differ between releases and different platforms. Cocoa apps (or any app which
links with the Foundation framework) can use NSLog() to get this functionality.
*/

void show(CFStringRef formatString, ...) {
   CFStringRef resultString;
   CFDataRef data;
   va_list argList;
   va_start(argList, formatString);
   resultString = CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArguments(NULL, NULL, formatString, argList);
   va_end(argList);
   data = CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(NULL, resultString, 
   CFStringGetSystemEncoding(), '?');
   if (data != NULL) {
      printf ("%.*s\n", (int)CFDataGetLength(data), CFDataGetBytePtr(data));
      CFRelease(data);
   }
   CFRelease(resultString);
}

int main(void)
{

   // To use:
   int age = 25;
   CFStringRef name = CFSTR("myname");

   show(CFSTR("Name is %@, age is %d"), name, age);

   return 0;
}
```